# send errors from "docker build" directives to stderr instead of stdout?

Tags: linux, docker, logging, stderr, aws-codebuild

When building a docker images, errors that are caused by `RUN` commands are printed to stdout instead of stderr. For example:

If I run the command `flooby` on my shell, the fact that it fails because the command isn't found is printed to stderr:

```
$ flooby 2> err.log
$ cat err.log
bash: flooby: command not found
```

However, if I am building a Docker image with the line `RUN flooby` in it, although (presumably) within the container/image/whatever that is being built, the error would print to stderr, docker prints it to stdout:

```
$ docker build -t stderr-test . 2> err.log
Sending build context to Docker daemon  121.1MB
Step 1/2 : FROM ruby:2.6
 ---> d98e4013532b
Step 2/2 : RUN flooby
 ---> Running in 118f7d467b43
/bin/sh: 1: flooby: not found
$ cat err.log
The command '/bin/sh -c flooby' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Here we can see that what would have been printed to stderr is printed to stdout, and what gets printed to stderr is **Docker's** message that there was a problem running `flooby` with an error code.

This is causing problems in CI when I want to aggregate logs and be able to filter them based on log level (info/error). Knowing that `flooby` returned a non-zero code 127 is worthless. I need to know *what the error output from running flooby was*.

Does anyone know how to get `docker build` to print error messages from the build directives to print to stderr rather than stdout?

Comment: Same question here...
Seems like nobody have the same issue....

Comment: This has gotten pretty much worse since buildkit, as now everything is logged into stderr --> https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1186